# Reading kernel memory using a module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

As part of my project I need to read the kernel to get the memory address of system call table and system call address. Or in effect i need to extract the contents of the system call table and all the system calls.

Till now I use GDB for this purpose. Is there any way so that I could do it using a kernel module. I am new the kernel module programming. Looking for advice from experts here.

Comment: How do you do it in gdb?

Comment: @Fredrik, you can use the following for example: `gdb vmlinux /proc/kcore`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me first start by saying reading arbitrary kernel memory is tricky business! And there are many ways to do it, which vary in their degree of complexity and flexability.

### 1) Hard-code the address.

Search for it in your kernel version's System.map file:

```
# grep sys_call_table /boot/System.map-2.6.18-238.12.1.el5
c06254e0 R sys_call_table
```

With this, hard-code the address:

```
unsigned long *syscall_table = (unsigned long *)0xc06254e0;
```

Then, assuming you `#include <linux/syscalls.h>`, you can use the `__NR_syscall` definitions to grab the addresses of those syscalls within the code:

```
syscall_table[__NR_close]
```

This is the easiest method, but by far the least flexible. This module will only work on that exact kernel. If you insmod it into a different kernel, you're liable to get a kernel OOPs.

### 2) Brute-force scan for the table

Have a look at this:

http://memset.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/syscall-hijacking-dynamically-obtain-syscall-table-address-kernel-2-6-x-2/

He uses a method to brute force the kernel memory address range to find the sys_call_stable. As-is, it only works on 32bit (64bit has a different memory address range for the kernel).

This method is somewhat flexible, but may break down the road as the kernel semantics change.

### 3) Dynamically search System.map load time

You can read your kernel's System.map file when you load the module. I demonstrate this in the *tpe-lkm* module I wrote. The project is hosted on github.

Have a look at the find_symbol_address_from_file() from this file:

https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm/blob/master/symbols.c

Very flexible, as you can find any symbol you want, but reading files from kernel space is a big 'no no'. Don't ask me why, but people are always telling me that. You also run the risk that the System.map it looks at is invalid, and could cause a kernel OOPs. Also, the code is... messy.

### 4) Use kallsyms_on_each_symbol()

As of around kernel version 2.6.30, the kernel exports kallsyms_on_each_symbol(). We can thank the ksplice folks for that. With this you can't find the sys_call_table (it isn't in there for some reason), but you can find most other symbols.

Very flexible, very stable method of finding addresses of symbols, but somewhat complicated to understand ;)

I demonstrate this in my *tpe-lkm* project. Have a look at the find_symbol_callback() and find_symbol_address() function in this file:

https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm/blob/master/symbols.c