# New linux kernels, no lsm using lkms, no kernel hooks now what?

Tags: linux, kernel, call, sys, linux-security-module

For security reasons, the kernel ceased to export characters necessary for writing security modules in the form of loadable kernel modules (Linux Kernel Module, LKM) starting with version 2.6.24.

And you can't export `sys_call_table`, again for security reasons.

But then, **how can I filter filesystem requests**?

I'll state it simply: I want to hook the "open" function!

I don't want to have to compile my own version of the kernel, what's the point of drivers? It should work for all kernels.

Please help, thought I would have more freedom than Windows with Linux, but now I see the most precious parts of my life are blocked in Linux.

Comment: It's okay if you just want to do it for experimental purposes, but doing this using a LKM is not safe as pointed out in [this](http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/2007usenixwoot-exploitingconcurrency.pdf). You should go for a LSM implementation to be safe from TOCTOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a kernel module that can do this called [tpe-lkm](https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm). I've also mentioned it on some other questions similar to this here on StackOverflow:

- [access to the sys_call_table in kernel 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840324/access-to-the-sys-call-table-in-kernel-2-6/8841377)
- [Reading kernel memory using a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610733/reading-kernel-memory-using-a-module/6614661#6614661)
- [intercepting file system system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588386/intercepting-file-system-system-calls)

Hope one of these helps you out.

Comment: so i have to _hijack_ the sys_call_table
,thank you very much, hoped at least **linux** could have driver stack...